# how to add two parameters and get value in sql (convert code pl/sql to sql )

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsqldeveloper

```
function CF_TOTAL_AMTFormula return Number is
begin
  RETURN NVL(:AMOUNT,0)+ NVL(:CF_TAX,0);
end;
```

This function is created in PL/SQL and I want to create this function in SQL.

Comment: Huh?  Not a clue as to what you are asking.  Please edit the question. SQL does not have user-defined functions. Pl/sql does, which you can call in a sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

As OldProgrammer mentioned above, "SQL does not have user-defined functions". Maybe you just want to add two parameters together in SQL? It's pretty straightforward...

```
select NVL(:AMOUNT,0) + NVL(:CF_TAX,0) as CF_TOTAL_AMT from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, SQL does allow inline functions, but they are implemented in PL/SQL so I'm not sure whether they meet your requirement:

```
with function cf_total_amtformula
    ( amount number, cf_tax number ) 
    return number
as
begin
    return nvl(amount,0) + nvl(cf_tax,0);
end;
select amount, cf_tax
     , cf_total_amtformula(amount, cf_tax) as formula_result
from   -- inline view to provide demo data:
       ( select 123 as amount, .2 as cf_tax from dual
         union all
         select 123, null from dual
         union all
         select null, .2 from dual )
```

(requires Oracle 12.1 or later.)

Obviously you could just use `nvl(amount,0) + nvl(cf_tax,0)` directly without defining any function, or define a column in a view etc.

Answer (score 0):

Putting Bind parameters into a function definition doesn't work, and results in a `PLS-00049: bad bind variable` error.  I think what you are looking for is this:

```
function CF_TOTAL_AMTFormula(AMOUNT number, CF_TAX number) return Number is
begin
  RETURN NVL(AMOUNT,0)+ NVL(CF_TAX,0);
end;
```

Note that both `AMOUNT` and `CF_TAX` have had the leading colons `:` removed, and have been moved up to the function signature.

Once compiled with `create or replace ...` you can then call the function in SQL like so:

```
select CF_TOTAL_AMTFormula(121, 12.1) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

select amount, cf_tax
     , nvl(amount,0) + nvl(cf_tax,0)
from   -- inline view to provide demo data:
       ( select 123 as amount, .2 as cf_tax from dual
         union all
         select 123, null from dual
         union all
         select null, .2 from dual )